# VSC Linker fails to link function-declarations from other .cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker, linker-errors, mingw-w64

I have three files: test_1.cpp ; test_2.hpp; test_2.cpp

test_1.cpp includes test_2.hpp and contains the main() function, which calls a function called testfunction()

```
#include "test_2.hpp"

int main(){
      testfunction();
      return 0;
}
```

test_2.hpp declares void testfunction() without giving it its "orders"

```
 #ifndef test_2_guard
 #define test_2_guard

 #include <iostream>

 void testfunction();

 #endif //test_2_guard
```

test_2.cpp includes test_2.hpp and declares testfunction(){ [some code] }

```
 #include "test_2.hpp"

 void testfunction(){
     std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
     return;
 }
```

This gives me the following error message:

C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9YOXad.o:test_1.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `testfunction()'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Why doesn't this work?
In use visual studio code with Mingw-w64 and the extension "C/C++"

Comment: What's your compile command? Also, VS Code does not include a linker.

Comment: Please add the text of your `tasks.json` file. Did you modify it like the documentation told you here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson) The default tasks.json is setup to build a single source file into an executable. Without modification your code will have link errors if you have more than 1 source file.

Comment: @sweenish I don't know, how can I find that out?

Comment: @drescherjm ok, now I did that, but it still does not work.

Comment: `#include "testy_2.hpp"` is a typo.

Comment: After fixing the typo I mentioned in the previous comment and updating the `tasks.json` it worked for me  in VSCode without any issue.

Comment: @drescjerjm, yes that's true but the typo was only on stack overflow. In my code it is written the right way. sadly it still doesn't work for me. Do you maybe have another idea?